# How to read in a binary file and store the data at a pointer in C

Tags: c, file-io, elf

So I am working on a project and I am failing to put all the pieces together to make this work.  We need to read in the header of a binary file and store them at the specified pointer.

the function I am working in:

```
int read_header (FILE *file, elf_hdr_t *hdr);
```

I understand how to pass the info to the function but I am failing to understand how to read in to the specified pointer.  I have been trying to find information on this all day but cant really figure out my starting point... Thanks for any direction you can provide.

My code so far:

```
int read_header (FILE *file, elf_hdr_t *hdr)    
{
    int read;
    read = fread(hdr, 1, sizeof(hdr), file);
    fclose(file);
}
```

I want to know if I am doing what I am trying here, basically want to read in one byte at a time to the specified pointer.

Comment: Show the original declaration for what you pass as `hdr`. Are you declaring it in the caller as `elf_hdr_t hdr;` and then passing `&hdr` as the parameter? If you declared it as `elf_hdr_t *hdr` and pass `hdr`, then `read_header` receives a **copy** of the pointer and not the pointer itself and any changes to `hdr` in `read_header` will be lost when the function returns.

Comment: i am creating elf_hdr_t hdr; then elf_hdr_t *hdr_p = &hdr; and passing hdr_p to read_header

Comment: That works because `elf_hdr_t hdr;` declares `hdr` with *automatic storage type* providing adequate storage. Had you declared `elf_hdr_t *hdr;`, `hdr` would simply be an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: `sizeof(hdr)` is the size of a pointer. I think you want either `sizeof(*hdr)` or `sizeof(elf_hdr_t)`. I think you should show your real code. Your previous examples would not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `hdr` is a pointer, `sizeof(hdr)` will just be the size of a pointer.  You want `sizeof(*hdr)` or `sizeof(elf_hdr_t)` to get the size of the elf header struct that the pointer points at...

Comment: ah thats where my problem is coming it, thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

please re-read the MAN page for `fread()`

These two parameters: `1, sizeof(hdr),` are saying to read in `sizeof(hdr)` bytes, not to read in 1 byte